# Increasing resolution of Cartopy stock background?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I am trying to create a small application that will show zoomed in maps. If possible, I would like to avoid using map tiles.

Going off the example on this page: https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/matplotlib/intro.html

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mollweide())
ax.stock_img()
ax.set_extent([35,45,35,45])

plt.show()
```

result:
[image]

I realize that this is the nature of a bitmap image.

I am just wondering if there is some method I don't know about for showing it in a higher resolution/dpi?

And if not, is there any middle to solution between this and using, say, Open Streetmap tiles?

I think that in order to use a tiled map I would need to run my own server, but I will largely be showing the same few map sections repeatedly, so I would think there must be some way around this.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like `cartopy` package a downsampled version of the Natural Earth 'shaded relief and water' image as the stock image. You could try the original version ([available here](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-natural-earth-1/50m-natural-earth-i-with-shaded-relief-and-water/)) and use `ax.imshow` to load it (following the [source for `ax.stock_img`](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/_modules/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.html#GeoAxes.stock_img) quite closely).

```py
import os

import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.image import imread


ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mollweide())

source_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
fname = os.path.join('path_to_natural_earth', 'NE1_50M_SR_W.tif')
ax.imshow(imread(fname), origin='upper', transform=source_proj, 
          extent=[-180, 180, -90, 90])

ax.set_extent([35,45,36,46])

plt.show()
```

Unfortunately this only gives a little improvement (see below), depending the size of your area of interest.

with extent [35,45,35,45]:
[image: quick test]

with extent [35,45,36,46]:
[image]

Beyond this, I'd either use vector data for background (Natural Earth have political, physical and cultural vector data), look for a bigger tif, or go with the tiled approach. Stamen terrain might be suitable, as in [this cartopy example](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery/scalar_data/eyja_volcano.html) (or [older version](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.18/gallery/eyja_volcano.html)). Hope that's helpful!

Comment: Link to Stamen terrain does not work. Try: https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/examples/eyja_volcano.html

Answer (score 0):

I just found a way to improve the resolution of Natural Earth background images considerably. The spatial interpolation can be done with [imshow](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html), but its very slow - so I use [pyinterp](https://pangeo-pyinterp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for this part.

First, a [high-resolution Natural Earth image](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-raster-data/) has to be downloaded - I use this [one](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/raster/NE1_HR_LC_SR_W.zip). Then, the following code can be used to produce the below image

```
# Load modules
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
from PIL import Image
import PIL
import pyinterp

mpl.style.use("classic")

# Select background product
prod_bg = "NE1_HR_LC_SR_W"
path_data = "<path to file>"

# Load image and create geographic coordinates
file = path_data + prod_bg + "/" + prod_bg + ".tif"
PIL.Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = 233280000
image = np.flipud(plt.imread(file))  # (8100, 16200, optional: 3), RGB, 0-255
extent = (-180.0, 180.0, -90.0, 90.0)
dlon_h = (extent[1] - extent[0]) / (float(image.shape[1]) * 2.0)
lon = np.linspace(extent[0] + dlon_h, extent[1] - dlon_h, image.shape[1])
dlat_h = (extent[3] - extent[2]) / (float(image.shape[0]) * 2.0)
lat = np.linspace(extent[2] + dlat_h, extent[3] - dlat_h, image.shape[0])
crs_image = ccrs.PlateCarree()

# Add data rows at poles (-90, +90 degree)
lat_add = np.concatenate((np.array([-90.0]), lat, np.array([+90.0])))
image_add = np.concatenate((image[:1, ...], image, image[-1:, ...]), axis=0)
x_axis = pyinterp.Axis(lon, is_circle=True)
y_axis = pyinterp.Axis(lat_add)

# Define map projection and extent
crs_map = ccrs.Mollweide()
extent_map_geo = (35.0, 45.0, 35.0, 45.0)

# Compute map extent in projected coordinates
plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection=crs_map)
add_margin = np.array([-1.0, +1.0, -1.0, +1.0]) * 0.5
ax.set_extent(np.array(extent_map_geo) + add_margin, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE, edgecolor="black", ls="-", lw=1.0)
extent_map = ax.axis()
plt.close()

# Interpolation coordinates
x_ip = np.linspace(extent_map[0], extent_map[1], 3000)
y_ip = np.linspace(extent_map[2], extent_map[3], 3000)
coord = crs_image.transform_points(crs_map, *np.meshgrid(x_ip, y_ip))
lon_ip = coord[:, :, 0]
lat_ip = coord[:, :, 1]
mask = np.isfinite(lon_ip)

# Spatial interpolation of image
image_ip = np.zeros(mask.shape + (3,), dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(3):
    grid = pyinterp.Grid2D(x_axis, y_axis, image_add[:, :, i].transpose())
    data_ip = pyinterp.bivariate(
        grid, lon_ip[mask].ravel(), lat_ip[mask].ravel(),
        interpolator="bilinear", bounds_error=True, num_threads=0)
    image_ip[:, :, i][mask] = data_ip

# Plot
plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection=crs_map)
ax.imshow(np.flipud(image_ip), extent=extent_map, transform=crs_map)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE, edgecolor="black", ls="-", lw=1.0)
ax.set_extent(extent_map_geo, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

[image]

Furthermore, you find another example (for a different map projection) [here](https://github.com/ChristianSteger/Map_plot/blob/main/plot_multiple_COSMO_domains.py)